# How can I change the name of my user folder? But not change the name of the user

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I accident moved my Desktop location from OneDrive to my User folder and this changed the name of my User folder to "Desktop". I did this be right clicking on my Desktop folder and choosing the User folder as the new location. My intention was to put my Desktop folder inside my User folder, but I messed up.

I moved my Desktop folder by editing the registry but now I am stuck with my user folder being called "Desktop". In CMD and in properties it is called "Bob" as it should be, but the actual icon in file explorer is Desktop. This remains after restart.

Is there a way to change the name of the "Desktop" folder to something else?

FYI I deleted my older question instead of editing it because it is a different question now.

Comment: I am not sure you can. You may need to back things up and make a new Windows User Profile.

Comment: @John nah, easy change

Answer (score 1):

Your folder did not actually change name. Only a hidden desktop.ini file was placed that makes Explorer change the name of the folder when viewing it, and giving it a different icon.

The easiest way to undo the change, is to simply perform the operation again, and selecting a different location. This should remove the desktop.ini file and set it up at the new location.

If that doesn't work, open a command prompt, navigate to the folder that is now wrong (note, in cmd you will still see your old folder, eg `cd /d c:\users\behacad`. Inside, type `attrib desktop.ini +a -rsh` to make the desktop.ini file visible, then delete it either from explorer or by typing `del desktop.ini`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there is no longer a "location" option in the properties for the folder so I can't move it. I tried command prompt and it says "invalid switch - - rsh"

Comment: try `attrib desktop.ini +a -r -s -h` instead

Comment: that did not seem to do anything. There is a Desktop "configuration settings" file in my new desktop folder, does that matter? I don't see one in my Users folder.

Comment: Yes, that is desktop.ini. Delete that file to make things return back to normal.

Comment: sorry maybe there's a misunderstanding. The destop.ini file is NOT in my user folder with the inappropriately named "Desktop" folder, but is rather in my appropriately named Desktop folder so I don't know why I would delete it.

Comment: If you type the following in CMD, do you see Desktop or your actual username? `cd /d c:\users` and then `dir`?

Comment: I see the proper name. Everywhere it seems to say the proper name other than inside file explorer. It also has the Desktop icon and because it is called Desktop I can see myself putting the wrong stuff in there!

Comment: So that confirms it. Inside your userfolder there MUST be a desktop.ini file. By default its hidden and has system attribute set to it, which is why you need to run the attrib command in your user folder to make it visible. Sounds like you ran the attrib command in the wrong place.

Comment: I have hidden folders visible and I do see the desktop.ini in the proper folder but not in that one. I also did run the commands you said without any change so I don't know how else to proceed.

Comment: One thing I can think of that definitely should fix this: from the correct desktop folder, right-click, properties, location tab and move it to c:\users\behacad, then after it asks you if you want to move your files, say no. Hit ok to go out of the dialog, then go to c:\users\behacad and in the location tab, move it back to where it should be. Again, make sure you DONT move files. This should restore the users folder.

Comment: last time I put the desktop where my user account was there was no location tab afterwards so I'm a bit hesitant to try this.

Comment: Aha, so that's what broke it then. What was the change in registry you mentioned? What if you change that one back to the users folder?

Comment: It was on the users folder before and I had to pull it off so I'm not sure what putting it back there would achieve? I could maybe try but I don't want to mess things up further.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to view and to change location of Windows special folders with the free tool, [Special Folders View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html), from Nirsoft.

[image: Special Folders View: Downloads]

Though one can certainly call up the folder properties without this app, it speeds changing locations for many special folders when adding a drive.

Comment: The problem is not that I want to move my Desktop, the problem is that my user folder is called Desktop. This does nothing to address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... it's mostly just a cosmetic fix from what you're describing, shouldn't be much of an issue.

**Option 1:**
Open the user folder in explorer, then open folder option from the toolbar, and enable show hidden folders and show operating system files. You'll see a `desktop.ini` file just copy and paste it back to the desktop or delete it. It will be recreated immediately or after a reboot.

**Option 2**
Do the same as option one, except instead of moving or delete it, double click it to open and change the name there.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't see a desktop file in the User folder at all, though I do see one in my newly designated Desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

instead of deleting the desktop.ini file as it will just be recreated (well in my case anyway) i poke things and discovered that if you open the ini file in notepad, and change the `localizedresourcename=@ systemroot system32 windows.storage.dll -21826` to l`ocalizedresourcename= your name` it will change the name of the folder and stay that way, then just customise folder to get the right icon,
this is of course if it says in the registry string-

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1885185601-4012364828-109957530-1001 - ProfileImagePath is C:\Users\yourname,
```

so far it has not changed back, whereas deleting the ini file just lasted till i opened something from inside the folder then recreated it, i hope this helps